# Why won't this CSS declaration display?

Tags: css, colors

Is there any reason why CSS declaration won't display in the browser?

Here's a sample of my CSS file:

```
.adv {
color:#47463D;
}

.earnings {
color:#B4FF00;
}
```

When I do `<font class=adv>hello</font>`, it works a treat.

When I do `<font class=earnings>hello</font>`, the color specified for `.earnings` doesn't display in the browser.

The page is linked to the correct CSS file.

Comment: You forgot the ; at the end of the color definition for the earnings class.  Not to mention you're using <font></a> which isn't correct, either.

Comment: 1. `font` tag is deprecated since like html4. 2. close your tags properly - you open `font` than close `a`.

Comment: You have an opening FONT tag  and a closing A tag. I have a hunch you have very invalid HTML which isn't helping.

Comment: Sorry, fixed up the issue. I just wrote it wrong in the q

Comment: As mentioned the `font` tag is deprecated. Use the `span` tag.

Comment: @snkmchnb actually since color is last property for this selector omitting `;` is fine.

Comment: My guess is you have other CSS on the page over-riding this bit based on your HTML structure. Impossible for us to truly debug without seeing more of your markup and cSS.

Comment: @Litek true.  Not a good practice, though.

Comment: My eyes burn! Please, for god's sake, please replace to `span`. And while your at it, please add quotation for attributes (to make more XHTML — my favourite version), although that last one isn't illegal in normal HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are somewhere on your page you have a style whose specificity supersedes the `.earnings` (See [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)). CSS is applied by a weight scale, so anything with a higher weight (calculated specificity) takes priority over what you *think* may be applied.

Best thing to do is use something like Firebug (firefox extension) or Chrome's inspector to see what style *really is* applied.

---

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/78Exw/) (And, by the way, [CSS order is irrelevant](http://jsfiddle.net/78Exw/1/))

```
<style>
  /* what you think is applied */
  .foo { color: red; }

  /* What is being applied due to specificity */
  #bar .foo { color: green; }
</style>

<span class="foo">.foo</span> <!-- color is red -->

<div id="bar">
    <span class="foo">#bar .foo</span> <!-- color is actually green -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to surround your parameter values with quotes.  You also need to make sure your tags match up

```
<a class="adv">hello</a>
<font class="earnings">hello</font>
```

Finally, if you have multiple css parameters in `.earnings` you need to put a semi-colon after each one.

Comment: You only need quotes with xhtml

Comment: True, but with some browsers it can help reduce issues.  Especially if your properties have spaces in them (i.e. multiple classes).

Comment: aren't final semicolons technically optional?

Comment: Yes, final ones are.  But still, it won't hurt to include them.

Answer (score 2):

The last semicolon in a CSS declaration is optional, so that's not your problem.

Most likely you have other styling applied that has a higher precedence. The CSS precedence rules can be a bit weird; the most common stumbling point is that *a highly specific declaration takes precedence over subsequent declarations that are less specific*

Example from HTMLdog.com:

```
  div p { color: red; }
  p { color: blue; }
```

Using that stylesheet, any p elements within a div will be colored red, not blue.

What I really suggest you do is get a decent developer tools plugin for your browser (e.g. Firebug on Firefox) and look through the style tracing; it will tell you what is being overridden, and by what.

Answer (score 1):

Add a semi-colon after your color line.

```
.adv {
color:#47463D;
}

.earnings {
color:#B4FF00;
}
```

Also, you should be using double quotes around your classes in html, along with matching closing tags:

```
<font class="earnings">hello</font>
```

Your second font tag is getting parsed as inside your first one, and not showing up.

Comment: while the semicolon is a good habit, it's not needed after the last style attribute

Comment: Double-quotes in HTML are not required. If the attribute value fully consists of non-whitespace characters, omitting them won't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you intend to close a font tag with an a tag, but the following code works just fine:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CSS Color Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .adv {color:red;}
      .earnings {color:red;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class=adv>hello</div>
    <div class=earnings>hello</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), use the element inspector (because I do not remember that the semicolons and the quotes was obligatory in the class attribute) and try to see what other selectors are involving whith the class "earnings".

Can you put a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example of your problem?